# specifying R library path for RKernel in Anaconda Jupyter notebook

Tags: r, windows, anaconda

First let me preface this with the disclaimer that I'm new to R, but a longtime Python power user.  Given that I love the conda ecosystem and the Jupyter notebook, I'm trying to set them up as my R development environment as well.

So using the instructions at: https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer/jupyter-and-conda-r  I've set up a Jupyter Notbook that using an RKernel that should be hitting the installation of R installed in my Anaconda folder (I would think anyway).

Getting it setup was easy peasy and everything is working great for standard R stuff but my analysis requires some R libraries that are not available in r-essentials channel.  No problem, I think I know how to install an R library.  I go to "C:\Anaconda\R\bin\x64\Rgui.exe" and install rgdal, dismo, and some other packages.  To check my work I looked in C:\Anaconda\R\library and there they are.

But when I run a jupyter notebook from the Anaconda command prompt.  And start a new R notebook I get a "Error in library(dismo): there is no package called 'dismo'"  Wait a sec, I run a ".libPaths()" from the notebook and it looks like its pointing

Answer (score 6):

You can add `.libPaths('path_where_your_packages_are')` in a code cell at the beginning of your notebook to tell jupyter where your packages are. For me that was `.libPaths('~/R/win-library/3.2')` (work-around from discnerd who filed [this issue](https://github.com/sagemathinc/smc/issues/205) on github).

To find out the path to your packages, just install a random package in R and wait for the location to be printed to the console.

---

More details (likely specific to my system/installations): When running `.libPaths()` in R, I got 2 locations: one for which admin rights were required for writing, and one for which admin rights were not required for writing. While packages installed through R land in the location where admin rights are not required, jupyter looks at the location where admin rights are required.

Comment: I am having a similar problem: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59212970/installed-package-on-anaconda-not-accessible-in-jupyter-notebook). When I ran `libPaths`I have 3 different paths. After trying your solution I still can not access my package in Anaconda. Have you heard anything new about this sort of issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the path to your library with `installed.packages()`