# tcltk dependency when trying to use ordPens library in Anaconda R

Tags: r, package, jupyter

I've been wrestling with this for days, and while there seem to be a number of tcltk problems in StackOverflow, I can't find the key to unlock this. Hope someone can help.

I'm using Anaconda and Jupyter notebooks to access R. I'm running this on Windows 10. It works wonderfully most of the time. I'm trying to use the ordPens package, but when I call the library, I get an error. The error seems to be that it requires the tcltk package to be loaded, to use the ordPens package.

```
library(ordPens, verbose=TRUE)
```

> Warning message in find.package(package, lib.loc, quiet = TRUE, verbose = verbose):
>   "package 'ordPens' found more than once,
>   using the one found in 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.0/library/ordPens'"Warning message:
>   "package 'ordPens' was built under R version 3.3.2"Loading required package: tcltk
>
> Error: package 'tcltk' could not be loaded
>   Traceback:
>
> 1. library(ordPens, verbose = TRUE)
> 2. .getRequiredPackages2(pkgInfo, quietly = quietly)
> 3. stop(gettextf("package %s could not be loaded", sQuote(pkg)), 
>      .     call. = FALSE, domain = NA)

But tcltk can't be installed directly, as a normal package. Apparently this causes problems in non-WIndows environments, when it isn't always loaded at initial build. But tcltk does appear to be available.

```
capabilities("tcltk")
```

> tcltk: TRUE

I tried a workaround by installing ordPens into the directory used by my R console, rather than Anaconda, and then pointing Anaconda at that (drawing on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33442362/specifying-r-library-path-for-rkernel-in-anaconda-jupyter-notebook/34443380) post, which has helped in the past)  :

```
 .libPaths('C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.0/library')
```

but it still didn't work.

Any ideas? As a last resort, I could just save my outputs from the Jupyter/Anaconda environment, process them with ordPens in the R console, and then save back. But I'd love to know how to fix this - and really to understand what is going on.