# Installed package on Anaconda not accessible in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I installed Anaconda on an external drive `inode/directory/0C707E95707E84EC`. I opened Anaconda-Navigator to install r-aer in base(root). So far so good. Then I start Jupyter Notebook from `inode/directory/0C707E95707E84EC` and am unable to access the `aer` library. 
This all started last week. when I was unable to install `aer`and after a circus of affairs I finally ended up updating `Anaconda` and then having to delete and reinstall it. All I want to do is access `aer`on Jupyter Notebook. The image below (last image) shows `library(raer)`; I have tried many different command versions, e.g. `library("Raer")`and variations thereof.

I know that AER is installed in Anaconda [image: here]. Could this be a path issue?

[image: install in Anaconda]

[calling library in Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX2QW.png)

[image: opening juypter notebook]

Answer (score 1):

for any file on desktop (win 10) Jupyter Notebook can see that file without specifying  the path, try putting that file on desktop.
see this it could help: 
[specifying R library path for RKernel in Anaconda Jupyter notebook_Stack OverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33442362/specifying-r-library-path-for-rkernel-in-anaconda-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: thank you for your comment. I am using Linux. I have also already investigated and applied the solution to the link you left. I am still getting the same results

Comment: [link]https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/channels.html

)  , and see this at the end of the page [link](https://gist.github.com/nturaga/9d1897ab73c0929dbbdcef7b60cb04c0
) , for Conda packages and how to read them when you start Anaconda, hope it helps.

Comment: I finally solved the problem: deleted my "other" R dr. Initiated an new env. in Anaconda called r-tutorial. Installed r, aer, etc. that took about a week to solve. Holy Cow!